# Универсальный метод Java с параметрами

Tags: java

Есть класс `MyGeneric<T>` с полем `a`.
Нужно создать метод  `public T Add(T obj)` который реализует сумму `Integer` и конкатенацию строк `String`. Как такое провернуть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `this.a += obj;` ?

Comment: public T Add(T obj) { return this.a + obj; } да, исправил, но не спасло.

Answer (score 1):

Например, вот так:

```
private static class MyGeneric<T> {
    T value;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T add(T value) {
        if (value instanceof String)
            return (T) concat(this.value.toString(), value.toString());
        if (value instanceof Integer)
            return (T) sum((Integer) this.value, (Integer) value);

        return null;
    }

    private static Integer sum(Integer v1, Integer v2) {
        return v1 + v2;
    }

    private static String concat(String v1, String v2) {
        return v1 + v2;
    }
}
```